# Basic WebSocket Chat

Tags: c#, websocket, .net-4.6

My objective is to create a basic chat application using web sockets.
I've got a client setup, however I am getting a specific exception every time I try to receive text on the client's side specifically.

The exception I am getting is the following:

> The buffer type '166' is invalid. Valid buffer types are: 'Close', 'BinaryFragment', 'BinaryMessage', 'UTF8Fragment', 'UTF8Message'

I get this exception on the following line of code `var socketResult = await _socket.ReceiveAsync(segment, CancellationToken.None);` in the below code:

```
private readonly ClientWebSocket_socket;

private async Task ListenAsync(Action<string> textReceived)
{
    while (_socket.State == WebSocketState.Open || _socket.State == WebSocketState.CloseSent)
    {
        var buffer = new byte[1024];
        var segment = new ArraySegment<byte>(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);

        var socketResult = await _socket.ReceiveAsync(segment, CancellationToken.None); // problem occurs here

        if (socketResult.MessageType == WebSocketMessageType.Close)
        {
            await _socket.CloseAsync(WebSocketCloseStatus.NormalClosure, string.Empty, CancellationToken.None);
            break;
        }

        var text = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer, 0, socketResult.Count);

        textReceived(text);
    }
}
```

what am I doing wrong? similar code works fine to receive the text on the server side.

EDIT:

The server listens fine and the `_socket.ReceiveAsync` method runs as expected. It waits until a message has been published and only then does it move on to reply. If I don't listen on the client side, Everything works. However when I start the server to listen for the client messages then start the client to listen, the client breaks. I have tried sending a message first from the client and then starting to listen for the response afterwards and I still experience the same thing.
Below is the method I use to listen on the server side.

```
private static WebSocket _socket;

public async Task ListenAsync()
{
    while (_socket.State == WebSocketState.Open || _socket.State == WebSocketState.CloseSent)
    {
        var buffer = new byte[1024];
        var segment = new ArraySegment<byte>(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);

        var socketResult = await _socket.ReceiveAsync(segment, CancellationToken.None);

        if (socketResult.MessageType == WebSocketMessageType.Close)
        {
            await _socket.CloseOutputAsync(WebSocketCloseStatus.NormalClosure, string.Empty, CancellationToken.None);
            break;
        }

        var text = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer, 0, socketResult.Count);

        await PublishAsync($"Server received the following text: {text} @ {DateTime.Now:g}");
    }
}
```

This is the method I use to publish messages  from the server.

```
public async Task PublishAsync(string text)
{
    var bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(text);
    var buffer = new ArraySegment<byte>(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);

    await _socket.SendAsync(buffer, WebSocketMessageType.Text, true, CancellationToken.None);
}
```

Comment: You may be sending a invalid http character.  Try just sending digits 0 to 9 and see if you get an error.

Comment: @jdweng I start listening before I send any data, from my understanding it should just wait until I do send data from the server however it just breaks

Comment: On the server side after message is sent, does the server close the connection?  After the server sends add a line Console.ReadLine() so the app does close and see if the exception goes away.

Comment: The server side does not close the connection, it's waiting to receive, the listen method on the client is put into a long running task, which breaks. When I reach a point where I need to send data to the server from the client, it fails as the socket entered an aborted state after the receiving has failed client side.

Comment: Which direction is failing?  First you said "similar code works fine to receive the text on the server side."  Then "When I reach a point where I need to send data to the server from the client, it fails.

Comment: The issue is on the client's listen, see edits for server side code if it would help. However like I said, even when no data is being transferred and both the server and client are just being set up to listen, the client is the only one which breaks.